# Accessing an element using id (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

Scenario:  I have a form element with id = "shipping_address"

Will all of the following work:

```
var i = document.shipping_address;
var i = window.shipping_address;
var i = shipping_address;

var i = document.forms.shipping_address;
var i = windows.forms.shipping_address;
var i = forms.shipping_address:
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a running example:

```js
var i = document.shipping_address;
console.log(i);
var i = window.shipping_address;
console.log(i);
var i = shipping_address;
console.log(i);
var i = document.forms.shipping_address;
console.log(i);
var i = windows.forms.shipping_address;
console.log(i);
var i = forms.shipping_address;
console.log(i);
```

```html
<form id="shipping_address">
  <input type='text'/>
</form>
```

Also I created a JSFiddle to help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/hszknwn9/1/

please notice you have what I think is a typo in the last line:var i =

```
forms.shipping_address:
```

the : should be a ;

I corrrected it in jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can try all of them on Codepen.io, but I would use only:

```
var i = document.getElementById("shipping_address");
```

And then access [all the properties listed here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) according to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Those will not work.

If you are trying to assign the reference of your element with `id="shipping_address"`, the correct way would be:

```
var i = document.getElementById("shipping_address");
```

To access the individual fields (and their respective contents) of that element, you need to first access the array of elements in your `<form>` element, and then iterate through:

```
var fields = i.elements;
var responses = [];
for(var j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
    //perform actions on or with fields[j],
    // such as responses.push(fields[j].value);
    // which would put the value of each field
    // of the form into the responses array.
}
```

The `<form>` element is a special container for grouping individual `<input>` elements, each of which should specify its input type. For example,

```
<form id="shipping_address">
<input type="text" placeholder="Street Address/P.O. box"></input>
<input type="text" placeholder="Town/City Name"></input>
<input type="text" placeholder="State/Country Name"></input>
<input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code (if applicable)"></input>
</form>
```

Which would create 4 input simple text fields from which inputs could be gathered. Putting all of this together, we can create a function that returns an array containing all of the values of the input fields in your `shipping_address` form element:

```
function getAddress() {
    var i = document.getElementById("shipping_address");
    var fields = i.elements;
    var responses = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
        responses.push(fields[j].value);
    return responses;
}
```

And from there on you can handle that data however you wish.

There are many more input `type`s, I suggest you read the reference documentation at the [w3schools html form reference](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), which provides acceptable documentation for most of the elements.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Use this to get value of a element by referencing ID of the element:

```
document.getElementById('shipping_address').value;
```